# XML handling, how to check if an attribute contained in an element in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

following is the sample xml string:

```
<R  RMA="1"   UsrID="AXxxx"  FirstName="xx" LastName="yy" Email="dd" title="">  
    <Contract ContractNr="xxx1" ETC=""  TermRC=""  DESC=""  INVCOMMENT="" TermDate="03/01/2014" PO="XXX" DestRule="xxxx">     
        <Asset ID="12345" AXID="abcde"   RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID=""/>
        <Asset ID="67890" AXID="abcde1"  RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID=""/>
    </Contract>

    <Contract ContractNr="xxx2" ETC=""  TermRC=""  DESC=""  INVCOMMENT=""  TermDate="03/01/2014" DestRule="xxxx">    
        <Asset ID="54321" AXID="edcba"   RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID="" />
        <Asset ID="09876" AXID="edcba1"  RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID="" />
    </Contract>

    <Contract ContractNr="xxx1" ETC=""  TermRC=""  DESC=""  INVCOMMENT="" TermDate="03/01/2014" PO="XXX" >     
        <Asset ID="12345" AXID="abcde"   RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID=""/>
        <Asset ID="67890" AXID="abcde1"  RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID=""/>
    </Contract>    

    <Contract ContractNr="xxx1" ETC=""  TermRC=""  DESC=""  INVCOMMENT="" TermDate="03/01/2014" >     
        <Asset ID="12345" AXID="abcde"   RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID=""/>
        <Asset ID="67890" AXID="abcde1"  RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID=""/>
    </Contract>    
 </R>
```

I want to check if all  elements contain PO and DestRule attributes, if not, print false otherwise print true.

can SQL server do that, how to write the SQL statement?

Comment: Something like `select case when count(case when a.b.value('@PO', 'varchar(max)') is not null and a.b.value('@DestRule', 'varchar(max)') is not null then 1 end) = count(*) then 'True' else 'False' end from mytable cross apply mycol.nodes('R/Contract') as a(b);`?

Comment: Which elements, exactly - `/R/Contract`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xml        xml = '<R  RMA="1"   UsrID="AXxxx"  FirstName="xx" LastName="yy" Email="dd" title="">  
    <Contract ContractNr="xxx1" ETC=""  TermRC=""  DESC=""  INVCOMMENT="" TermDate="03/01/2014" PO="XXX" DestRule="xxxx">     
        <Asset ID="12345" AXID="abcde"   RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID=""/>
        <Asset ID="67890" AXID="abcde1"  RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID=""/>
    </Contract>

    <Contract ContractNr="xxx2" ETC=""  TermRC=""  DESC=""  INVCOMMENT=""  TermDate="03/01/2014" DestRule="xxxx">    
        <Asset ID="54321" AXID="edcba"   RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID="" />
        <Asset ID="09876" AXID="edcba1"  RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID="" />
    </Contract>

    <Contract ContractNr="xxx1" ETC=""  TermRC=""  DESC=""  INVCOMMENT="" TermDate="03/01/2014" PO="XXX" >     
        <Asset ID="12345" AXID="abcde"   RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID=""/>
        <Asset ID="67890" AXID="abcde1"  RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID=""/>
    </Contract>    

    <Contract ContractNr="xxx1" ETC=""  TermRC=""  DESC=""  INVCOMMENT="" TermDate="03/01/2014" >     
        <Asset ID="12345" AXID="abcde"   RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID=""/>
        <Asset ID="67890" AXID="abcde1"  RecvdDt="05/02/2014" ReconDt="05/02/2014" ReceiptID=""/>
    </Contract>    
 </R>'

IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT      NULL
         FROM       @xml.nodes('/R/Contract')   X(Contract)
         WHERE      Contract.value('@PO', 'varchar') IS NULL
                OR  Contract.value('@DestRule', 'varchar') IS NULL
    )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'some contracts do not have PO or DestRule'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'OK'
END
```